# Can't update Knockout.js ViewModel after .ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

On initial page load, my data gets loaded fine.  I have a delete function which calls my controller through .ajax and deletes the item in the database OK, and then sends back the new list of JSON items.  Everything works until I call ko.mapping.fromJS(data.newData, viewModel) and then the page just stalls out with no error messages.  If I add in an alert(data.newData) I see the correct Json.  Following is the code, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
<script>
var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

var viewModel = {
    trainingDocs : ko.observableArray(initialData)
};

function deleteDoc(doc) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/_DeleteTrainingDocument/"+doc.TrainingDocumentId,
        type: "POST",
        data: "",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Result) {
                $("#userMessage").html("<img src='/content/Status_1.png' align='bottom' />" + data.Message);
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data.newData, viewModel);
            } else {
                $("#userMessage").html("<img src='/content/Status_0.png' align='bottom' />" + data.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.body);
</script>

<table class="agent-info">
<thead>
    <tr> 
        <th>Title</th> 
        <th>Action</th> 
    </tr> 
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: trainingDocs">
    <tr> 
        <td><span data-bind="text:Title"></span></td> 
        <td><a href="#" id="whiteLinks" data-bind="click: function() { if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete '+$data.Title+'?')) deleteDoc($data) }">delete</a></td>
    </tr> 
</tbody>
</table>​
<div id="userMessage">
    Results
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also add your html showing the databindings?  Even better would be a jsfiddle showing your error

Comment: OK peacemaker, I edited my question and added the html.  I'm brand new to Knockout.js, so I've not gotten familiar enough with jsfiddle yet, even though I have seen some examples of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of the exact structure being returned from your AJAX call, but if to update your existing data you either need to:

- create your original observableArray using the mapping plugin like:

  `var viewModel = {
      trainingDocs : ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData)
  };`
- or pass in empty mapping options when updating in your callback like:

  `ko.mapping.fromJS(data.newData, {}, viewModel);`

Also, for the update call, I would pay close attention to what `data.newData` contains, because I would suspect that you may need to use `viewModel.trainingDocs` instead of just `viewModel`, if the data is the actual array.

Comment: Thanks RP!!!  "viewModel.trainingDocs instead of just viewModel" solved the problem, and your other comments were beneficial too.  Just getting started using the Knockout.js framework and it looks very useful.